# Please explain this method for comparing strings

Tags: c, pointers, string

Suppose, for example,  that some `k` which is an arbitrary number=2 `k=2`, then there is code in C:

```
int wordcomp(char *p, char *q) {
   int n = k;
   for ( ; *p == *q ; p++, q++) {
      if (  *p==0 && --n == 0 )
         return 0;
   }
   return *p - *q;  
}
```

Please explain to me what this code does? Also, what does `*p-*q` mean? Also, how is it implemented in Java?

Comment: I think you are missing some braces in that for loop - correct?

Comment: I added the braces, for clarity-

Comment: pls, stop tagging everything "algorithm" !!!

Comment: i wonder if this is a joke post.. even the function name is just "word compare" mis-spelled.

Comment: This question received a lot of downvotes, but hardly any explanation. It wasn't a terribly bad question, but it could've been formulated better. From your history of questioning on this site, I'm guessing it solely comes down to your written English.

Comment: @Shtééf: I agree, that's  is why we should -->

Comment: This code does unpredictable things if `k` is negative.  Too bad `n` isn't declared as unsigned.

Comment: @Jordan Lewis, That for loop doesn't actually need braces.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> *please explain me what does this code do?*

It compares two words

> *also what means* `*p-*q`?

It means, *Tell me the value of char the pointer p is pointing to, and rest it to the char the pointer q is pointing to.*

> *and also how implement it in java?*

The `*p-*q` part? Here is it.

```
// char c
// char k
c - k;
```

If you mean the whole function, this could help you to get started:

```
int wordcomp( String sp, String sq) {
   int n = k; // I have no idea what is this for
   int pi = 0, qi = 0;
   for ( ; sp.charAt(pi) == sq.charAt(qi) ; pi++, qi++) {
      if (  sp.length()==pi && --n == 0 )
         return 0;
  }
  return sp.charAt(pi) - sq.charAt(qi);
```

You need to validate limits tough.

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful. Now if I could only get +20 I would have the reversal badge :P

Comment: yey! reversal after only 3 years :)

Answer (score 3):

Looks to be close to strcmp.  It takes two string pointers, loops over them until it finds a character that is different, and then returns a positive value if p is alphabetically after q, a negative value if p is alphabetically before q, or 0 if they are the same.  As stated by others, k looks to define the number of consecutive null-terminated strings to compare before it just returns 0.

Comment: It is more similar to strncmp. But for some reason he initializes n variable in the function body. If he will do 
int wordcomp(char *p, char *q, int n) it would be the same strncmp.

Comment: Not quite, remember n only gets decremented when it hits a null, so it is comparing n strings, not n bytes.

Answer (score 1):

`*p-*q` means subtract the value pointed to by pointer q from the value pointed to by pointer p.

this being C, subtracting 2 char values means subtracting their ASCII codes.

Answer (score 1):

This function loops through two character arrays, comparing them for equality.

If they are unequal, it returns *p - *q, which is the difference between the values in the first unequal position. If, after the kth zero in the first string, there is still no inequality, then it returns 0.

So it returns the difference between the values in the first unequal position, or 0 if the first string has k zeros and is equal until that point to the second string.

Comment: "If the kth character [of the first argument] is equal to 0, then it returns 0". Right. And it makes little sense, probably a bug.

Comment: Yeah, if this is trying to be a strcmp, it is not doing a very good job :)

Comment: No, what it does is compare the strings until the kth zero. So if k==1 it will be the same as strcmp.

Comment: No, not the kth character, the kth null.   && is short-circuiting so it would only execute the -- each time it got to a 0.

Answer (score 0):

Returns the difference between the first two dissimilar `char`s in two character arrays (`*p` and `*q`) of maximum length `k`, i.e.

```
batter
batsman
```

**Returns** `'t'-'s'`

If both strings are same for length `k` **and** we reach the null character of `p`, we return `0`. I think it should be `||` not `&&` since these are termination conditions.

Comment: And it looks like `k` is the number of consecutive null-terminated strings stored in `p` and `q`.

Comment: I think it's `min(strlen(p),strlen(q))`

Comment: @Shteef - no, p and q are not arrays of strings. They are character arrays.

Comment: @Jordan Lewis: When `p` hits the null terminator, `n` is decremented and the loop continues, until `n` reaches 0. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I think it should be `||` not `&&`

Comment: Not necessarily. n is decremented only if *p==0, but it is probably by design. It's pretty obfuscated but there were worse things people came up with. So n stores the number of consecutive null terminated strings.

Answer (score 0):

It compares to char arrays (words) to the element set in k.
Lets say if you have k=4 it means it will compare first 4 chars.
Also I believe instead of

```
if (  *p==0 && --n==0)
```

you need

```
if (  *p==0 || --n==0)
```

And also please consider using `p - q` .

And the function name must be `wordcomp` instead of `wrodcomp`.

So to summarize it is something like [`strncmp`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strncmp) from `string.h`.